# Display MySQL records horizontally

Tags: php, mysql

Generally we fetch data from MySQL table and display the fetched records in rows one by one. But sometimes we need to display the records horizontally as below.

```
Name * Student-ID * subject-1 * subject-2 * subject-3 * subject-4 * subject-5 ... So On
John      1            20           50          34          50         45 
Mercy     3            40           20          82          23         10
James     8            30           60          40          50         30
Agi       19           50           10          23          45         30
```

Now am looking for a way which can produce the results as mentioned above. Below are MySQL tables which I would like to come-up with the above desired results.

Table **subjects** Stores subjects by class as follows

1. subjectid
2. subjectname
3. examinationid

Table examinfo Stores examination information follows

1. assessment_id
2. idsubject

Table **examinations** Stores Student Scores  alongside relevant information follows

1. studentid
2. fname
3. lname
4. id_subject
5. score

   - examinationid == assessment_id
   - id_subject AND idsubject == subjectid

To Query All Students Of a class who sat for examination with id examinationid (1)

```
SELECT *
FROM examinations AS exam
INNER JOIN examinfo AS info ON info.idsubject = exam.id_subject
WHERE info.assessment_id = 1
```

The above query will produce results **vertically** so How to transform or query the table Horizontally. am missing it because I never use SQL in this way before. Thanks for your hand

Comment: You've tagged this with PHP. Generally, it's best to handle issues of data display at the application level/presentation layer (e.g. a simple PHP loop)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for MYSQL pivot

**STATIC WAY**:
Use conditional case with group by

```
SELECT CONCAT(exam.fname," ",exam.lname) AS Name, exam.studentid, 
 SUM(CASE WHEN exam.id_subject = 1 THEN exam.score ELSE "NA" END) AS subject1,
 SUM(CASE WHEN exam.id_subject = 2 THEN exam.score ELSE "NA" END) AS subject2,  
 SUM(CASE WHEN exam.id_subject = 3 THEN exam.score ELSE "NA" END) AS subject3,
 SUM(CASE WHEN exam.id_subject = 4 THEN exam.score ELSE "NA" END) AS subject4,  
 SUM(CASE WHEN exam.id_subject = 5 THEN exam.score ELSE "NA" END) AS subject5
FROM examinations AS exam
INNER JOIN examinfo AS info ON info.idsubject = exam.id_subject
WHERE info.assessment_id = 1
GROUP BY exam.studentid
```

**DYNAMIC WAY**: Use [GROUP_CONCAT](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/aggregate-functions-and-grouping/aggregate-functions-and-grouping-group_concat.php) with [CONCAT](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-concat-function.php)

```
SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT 
    CONCAT('SUM(CASE WHEN id_subject= "', 
    id_subject, '" THEN score ELSE "NA" END) AS '
    , 'Subject-', id_subject))
INTO @sql
FROM
  examinations;

SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT CONCAT(fname," ",lname) AS Name, 
                   studentid, ', @sql, ' 
                  FROM examinations
                  INNER JOIN examinfo AS info ON info.idsubject = id_subject
                  WHERE info.assessment_id = 1
                  GROUP BY studentid');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

Comment: @firstmadcoding: Please check and reply ?

Comment: Rockse is flowing an error: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '), (CASE WHEN exam.subjectid = 2 THEN exam.score ELSE "NA"), (CASE WHEN exam' at line 2

Another thing my subjects are limited

Comment: @firstmadcoding: Now its good, forgot to use END, please check

Comment: The problem was on last END i remove comma(,) It should not have comma it works but everything is NULL

Comment: Are you not even getting name and studentid ? Please add sqlfiddle if possible.

Comment: rockse i then tested the above response it works but both querry have been limited to 5 subjects cos my example was showing 5 but i include .... so on meaning i need all subjects from table subject where examinationid = 1, can that be possible rockse?

Comment: possible, i have added a dynamic way to get the result, check that out :)

Comment: It have executed but return empty results am trying to play around with it the problem it has subject- i hope you were looking for subject_id

Comment: still more cant get it empty results, please observe my subjectid, idsubject, id_subject i blv is where am getting empty results as i cant understand what your code is try'n to mean here 
SELECT
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT 
    CONCAT('SUM(CASE WHEN subjectid= "', 
    subjectid, '" THEN score ELSE 0 END) AS '
    , 'Subject-', subjectid)) if i can understand you there i can diagnose the code otherwise you done a good job

Comment: give me a min, i will revert :)

Comment: still no results, 'subject-' is returning an error what is it? when i change it to one of these subjectid, idsubject, id_subject the query return empty results.

Comment: Please prepare a sqlfiddle, I will help you for sure, no worries. Please post the link of your sqlfiddle :))

Comment: I never use sqlfiddle, i try to paste my three database table and run sql query it works but when i open new browser am not able to access the information how to save and provide link to you. if possible can i just send you the tables? what will b the way?

Comment: Rockly so far thanks for your kindness you meant to really help me to have successful project your quarries works so fine on fibble expect the last one, the one am looking for still return zero on my server. I took my time thinking why this is happing now three days and why I should fall finish my project just for this query. It seems I didn’t provide you with enough information. The tables you are dealing with are archive tables that’s why you see idsubject, subject_id, subjectid, id_subject idexam, assessment_id verse verses this ID’s will produce incorrect information and

Comment: and table examinations to get certain class examination papers which was sat in certain year requires IN(SELECT)  statement and from a table which I didn’t mention in my example. Then I would like to ask if possible I can upload RAR file to my email outbox and give u the password to download detailed information or you can gave me email address to email it or where to upload and you download.

It’s like this because I was thinking the sql query to be the answer will involve left join examination table several times or involve union. Thanks and regards

Answer (score 0):

Use below query

```
SELECT CONCAT(exam.fname," ",exam.lname) AS Name, exam.studentid, 
 (CASE WHEN exam.subjectid = 1 THEN exam.score END ),
 (CASE WHEN exam.subjectid = 2 THEN exam.score END ),  
 (CASE WHEN exam.subjectid = 3 THEN exam.score END ),
 (CASE WHEN exam.subjectid = 4 THEN exam.score END ),  
 (CASE WHEN exam.subjectid = 5 THEN exam.score END ),
FROM examinations AS exam
INNER JOIN examinfo AS info ON info.idsubject = exam.id_subject
WHERE info.assessment_id = 1
GROUP BY exam.studentid
```

Comment: don't mine but atleast remove the comma from last END, it will show an error. You copied a little wrong from my query :P

Comment: On my server is working without comma that should not be a problem better it works, but the problem the query is limited to 5 subjects is there a way to unlimit it? like also joining table subject where examinationid = 1